# Is is_dir() unreliable, or are there race conditions that can be mitigated here?

Tags: php, directory, php-5.4

At work, I've inherited a web application that has a file upload process. Part of this process occasionally (once every two weeks or so) triggers the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): File exists in {{{file_path_name_redacted}}} on line 7
```

Looking at lines 6-8, gives us:

```
if(!is_dir($storeFolder)){
    mkdir($storeFolder, 0644, TRUE);
}
```

Given this file can be hit by multiple PHP processes, I believe race conditions *may* be coming into play here. I've seen the same problem on other sites that I've managed in the past, similarly occurring only once in a blue moon.

What I believe is happening is that users are double-clicking on the upload button, which causes two PHP processes to execute at almost exactly the same time, like this:

```
Process 1 executes line 6 - dir does not exist
Process 2 executes line 6 - dir does not exist
Process 1 executes line 7 - directory is created
Process 2 executes line 7 - directory cannot be created as it already exists
```

Is this a case of race conditions, as I explained above (i.e. has anyone else noticed this), and/or is there some way of mitigating the error other turning off error reporting for warnings?

Comment: Might be worthwhile checking `file_exists()` as well, otherwise if `$storeFolder` exists as a file (rather than a directory), then `is_dir()` willl validly return false, but `mkdir()` will fail

Comment: I'll try that, but the artifacts in the parent folder are only ever created by this process. i.e. only directories are ever in that folder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Php inspections confirms that a [race condition exists](https://github.com/kalessil/phpinspectionsea/blob/master/docs/probable-bugs.md#mkdir-race-condition), and suggests that the safest way to write your code is:

```
if (!is_dir($dir) && !mkdir($dir) && !is_dir($dir)) {
    throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Directory "%s" could not be created', $dir));
}
```

[<s>A bit more of explanation</s>](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/49427500-mkdir-race-condition-enhancement)   (Edit: link is dead see link above)

It feels strange, but it certainly works. Best of luck.

Comment: I'm not in a position to test this any more, as I've left my previous workplace, but the links you've provided explain the situation precisely. I wouldn't be surprised if this works, as `is_dir` and `mk_dir` may call different processes that are queued up differently. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

I have seen many projects use [Hugues D's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57939677/424381), which seems to work quite well.  However, it can fail when using `$recursive = true`, because of [a bug in PHP reported in 2005](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=35326), which they somehow refuse to fix (yes, it *is* a bug).

Here's a snipped that has served me well so far:

```
/**
 * Safer version of mkdir(..., ..., true) without race condition issues
 *
 * @see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=35326
 *
 * @param string $dirname A directory path to create
 * @param int    $mode    Permission
 */
function safeMkdirRecursive(string $dirname, int $mode = 0777): void {
    $current = '';
    foreach (explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $dirname) as $part) {
        $current .= $part;
        if ($current !== '' && !@mkdir($current, $mode) && !is_dir($current)) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Failed to create directory: ' . $current);
        }
        $current .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I have not tested this on Windows!